# Logged as another user

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, csom, user-accounts, kerberos

UPDATE : I've totally disabled the Distributed Cache, however, the problem is still there.

---

For the record, I've applied CU7 for AppFabric as well as SharePoint 2013 Server March '13 CU. No luck so far.

---

One of our team have been deploying a new website using SharePoint API in order to post documents in a dedicated SP2013 Web Application's document library, totally standard one.
Their website's web.config points specifically to the url to this web app.

Works well, so far.

However, since they are using this web site fonctionality, posting documents, any user on *any other web application* may be temporarily logged as the user which has been using this site (Sharepoint logs point me to this).

And that's an issue.

I've been looking around for some information, signs point to - maybe - kerberos and WFE load balancing. For information, Kerberos is fine on all of our webapps, no SPN duplicates or stuff like that. But I'm stuck right now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what you saying, you have a web site( non sharepoint) which will upload the documents in the SharePoint site..right? and what is the issue with user?

Comment: The user, let's say "user1", who uploads the document via the external website has no issues. However, the users browsing other web applications hosted on the same farm that the web app where documents are uploaded, may be temporarily logged as "user1". Whatever the web application they are browsing.

Comment: Which SharePoint API are you using?

Comment: Dunno which code the devs used, but I have a sample :         string serverUrl = SharepointService.GetServerUrl();
               log.Info("server url : "+serverUrl);
               using (var clientContext = new SC.ClientContext(serverUrl))
               {
                   log.Info("client context initialized");
                   try
                   {
                       clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web.CurrentUser);
                       clientContext.ExecuteQuery();  

                   }

Comment: That's CSOM. I think the problem may be somewhere in code, not SharePoint configuration. Can you provide us with the code you're using to upload documents?

Comment: Here you go : http://pastebin.com/msrTyZm1

Comment: have you considered that the id's of users is not the same on different SharePoint sites and that may be causing you problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to tell you that we figured out the problem.
Some time ago, indeed, and I apologize for not having mentioned the solution here.

The problem was due to our F5 Load Balancer, as an additional configuration was needed. 
I was able to fix the issue thanks [to this article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/48ceb461-170c-4540-b6a7-e367916f6f1c/user-display-name-changes-in-sharepoint-when-using-kerberos?forum=sharepointadmin) :